# How to trigger a software generated interrupt on core1 from core1 on bare metal?

Tags: interrupt, xilinx, zynq, zynq-ultrascale+

I'm trying to trigger a software generated interrupt on core1 from `core0` on the Zynq Ultrascale+ Platform. Sadly however no interrupt ever reaches `core1`.

I tried multiple approaches also using the `xscugic` driver example. But it only worked from `core0` to itself (see driver example) never to `core1`. This post is my last resort. Can anyone help? What am I missing?

My code currently looks like this:

```
int ScuGicInit(XScuGic *IntcInstancePtr, u16 DeviceId) {
    XScuGic_Config *IntcConfig;
    int status;

    // Get the configuration for the GIC
    IntcConfig = XScuGic_LookupConfig(XPAR_SCUGIC_SINGLE_DEVICE_ID);

    if (NULL == IntcConfig) {
        return XST_FAILURE;
    }

    // Initialize the GIC
    status = XScuGic_CfgInitialize(IntcInstancePtr, IntcConfig,
                                   IntcConfig->CpuBaseAddress);
    if (status != XST_SUCCESS) {
        return status;
    }

    // Register the GIC with the exception framework
    Xil_ExceptionRegisterHandler(XIL_EXCEPTION_ID_IRQ_INT,
                                 (Xil_ExceptionHandler)XScuGic_InterruptHandler,
                                 IntcInstancePtr);

    // Enable interrupts in the ARM
    Xil_ExceptionEnable();

    return XST_SUCCESS;
}
```

```
#define INTC_DEVICE_ID      XPAR_SCUGIC_0_DEVICE_ID
#define INTC_DEVICE_INT_ID  0x0E

void core1(void){
     int Status;
    XScuGic IntcInstance;

    // Initialize GIC
    Status = ScuGicInit(&IntcInstance, XPAR_SCUGIC_SINGLE_DEVICE_ID);
    if (Status != XST_SUCCESS) {
        // Handle error condition
        //return XST_FAILURE;
    }

    // Connect the SGI handler provided by Core1
    Status = XScuGic_Connect(&IntcInstance, INTC_DEVICE_INT_ID,
                             (Xil_InterruptHandler)DeviceDriverHandler, &IntcInstance);
    if (Status != XST_SUCCESS) {
        // Handle error condition
        //return XST_FAILURE;
    }

    // Enable the SGI interrupt
    XScuGic_Enable(&IntcInstance, INTC_DEVICE_INT_ID);

    // Core1 main loop
    while (1) {
        // Core1's tasks or sleep
    }

    while (1);
}


int main() {
    int Status;
    XScuGic IntcInstance;

    // Initialize GIC
    Status = ScuGicInit(&IntcInstance, XPAR_SCUGIC_SINGLE_DEVICE_ID);
    if (Status != XST_SUCCESS) {
        // Handle error condition
        return XST_FAILURE;
    }

    set_start_addr();
    release_acpus();

    sleep(1);

    // Core0 main loop
    while (1) {
        // Trigger an SGI to Core1
        // Assuming Core1 has been configured to handle SGI ID 0
        XScuGic_SoftwareIntr(&IntcInstance, INTC_DEVICE_INT_ID, XSCUGIC_SPI_CPU1_MASK);
        sleep(1);

        // Add a delay or triggering condition here as necessary to prevent continuous triggering
    }

    return XST_SUCCESS;
}
```

`set_start_addr()` and `release_acpus()` are verified to work properly. The Main function runs on `core0` while the function `core1` runs on `core1`.

If found the **solution**. Core 0 initalizes its SCR_EL3 Register like so:

```
    mov      w1, #0                 //; Initial value of register is unknown
    orr      w1, w1, #(1 << 11)     //; Set ST bit (Secure EL1 can access CNTPS_TVAL_EL1, CNTPS_CTL_EL1 & CNTPS_CVAL_EL1)
    orr      w1, w1, #(1 << 10)     //; Set RW bit (EL1 is AArch64, as this is the Secure world)
    orr      w1, w1, #(1 << 3)      //; Set EA bit (SError routed to EL3)
    orr      w1, w1, #(1 << 2)      //; Set FIQ bit (FIQs routed to EL3)
    orr      w1, w1, #(1 << 1)      //; Set IRQ bit (IRQs routed to EL3)
    msr      SCR_EL3, x1
```

Especially the IRQ bit is of interest. Apparently this needed to be set on all CPUs that are running bare metal (EL3) to receive any kind of IRQ. After setting this bit on Core1, Core0 was able to trigger a interrupt.

Comment: There are multiple ways around this problem.
One way is to connect connect them using PL. Generate an interrupt signal from core0 (via axi GPIO and connect it to zynq interrupt). In core 1, use that specific interrupt ID and write an ISR for that. This way core0 can generate a signal that is propagated to PL and then received in core1.

But the ideal solution us to directly generates an interrupt from core0 to core1. I have already done that, but I am away from my PC so it will take me some time to answer that.

Comment: It would be great if you could provide code samples. I can wait.